# EF Core: Handling DbUpdateException for PRIMARY KEY Constraint Violation on Nazione Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm working on a .NET 8 application using Entity Framework Core for ORM, AutoMapper for object mapping, and MediatR for CQRS pattern implementation.

I have two entities, `Provincia` and `Nazione`, with a foreign key relationship from `Provincia` to `Nazione`. The relationship is set up to ensure that a `Provincia` cannot exist without a corresponding `Nazione`. Here are the simplified versions of my classes:

```
public class Provincia : Entity<int>
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id_Provincia { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("Cd_Nazione", TypeName = "char(2)")]
    public string Cd_Nazione { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Required]
    [Column("Cd_Provincia", TypeName = "char(3)")]
    public string Cd_Provincia { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("Descrizione", TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
    public string Descrizione { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Cd_Nazione")]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Nazione Nazione { get; set; }
}
```

Nazione class:

```
public class Nazione : Entity<int>
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Column("Id_Nazione", TypeName = "int")]
    public int Id_Nazione { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column("Cd_Nazione", TypeName = "char(2)")]
    [Required]
    public string Cd_Nazione { get; set; }

    [Column("Descrizione", TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
    [Required]
    public string Descrizione { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Provincia> Provincia { get; set; }
}
```

`CreateProvinceCommand` handler snippet:

```
public async Task<CreateProvinceResponse> Handle(CreateProvinceCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await countryBusinessRules.CountryShouldBeExists(request.Cd_Nazione);
    await provinceBusinessRules.ProvinceCannotDuplicate(request.Cd_Provincia);
    
    Provincia? province = mapper.Map<Provincia>(request);
    var result = await provinceRepository.AddAsync(province);
    CreateProvinceResponse response = mapper.Map<CreateProvinceResponse>(result);

    return response;
}
```

When I attempt to create a new `Provincia` with an existing `Nazione`, I'm encountering a `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException` related to a primary key constraint violation on the `Nazione` entity.

The exception message is:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Nazione'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Nazione'

This occurs even when the `Cd_Nazione` I'm trying to associate with the `Provincia` already exists in the database.

```
public async Task CountryShouldBeExists(string cd_Nazione)
{
    cd_Nazione = cd_Nazione.ToLower();

    var result = await countryRepository
                           .AnyAsync(x => x.Cd_Nazione.ToLower().Equals(cd_Nazione), enableTracking: false);

    if (!result)
    {
        throw new BusinessException(CountryMessages.CountryNotFound);
    }
}
```

I'm puzzled as to why EF Core is trying to insert a new `Nazione` record when one with the given `Cd_Nazione` already exists, leading to the primary key constraint violation. I've made sure that the `Cd_Nazione` is correctly passed and exists in the database before calling `AddAsync` on the `Provincia`.

Has anyone faced a similar issue or can spot what I might be doing wrong here? How can I ensure that EF Core recognizes the existing `Nazione` and doesn't attempt to insert a new one, thus avoiding the primary key constraint violation?

Comment: Did you perform a migration update after making changes to the c# code?  Migration create a mapping between the c# classes and the database and you must do a Migration after any changes to the c# Entity Classes.

Comment: Yes I did update database

Comment: Can you show us the `CreateProvinceCommand ` class? And what does the AutoMapper do when mapping the `CreateProvinceCommand` to the `Provincia` class?

Comment: Key is not on the same property in the classes Provincia and Nazione

Comment: Please **UPDATE** your original question and post this new information there - nicely formatted. It's just a huge pile of mess in comments...

Answer (score 0):

```
using Doing.Retail.Core.Persistence.Repositories;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace Doing.Retail.Domain.Entities;

public class Provincia : Entity<int>
{
    public int Id_Provincia { get; set; }
    public string Cd_Nazione { get; set; }
    public string Cd_Provincia { get; set; }
    public string Descrizione { get; set; }
    public virtual Nazione Nazione { get; set; } = null!;

    public Provincia()
    {
      
        Cd_Nazione = string.Empty;
        Cd_Provincia = string.Empty;
        Descrizione = string.Empty;
    }
    public Provincia(int id_Provincia, string cd_Nazione, string cd_Provincia, string descrizione) : this()
    {
        Id_Provincia = id_Provincia;
        Cd_Nazione = cd_Nazione;
        Cd_Provincia = cd_Provincia;
        Descrizione = descrizione;
    }
}
```

This is fix my problem.

Comment: Care to explain ***WHAT*** the fix really is?